# Representing hundredths of seconds as an interval

Tags: oracle, time

Please help me in the below code to calculate the time HH:MI:SS:MS from DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time.

```
Declare
v_start_time number;
v_end_time number;
v_exec_time varchar2(100);
begin
v_start_time:=DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time;

dbms_output.put_line('Time calculation');

v_end_time:=DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time;

v_exec_time:= (v_end_time-v_start_time); --please help me here i want v_exec_time in the format of HH:MI:SS:MS)

end;
/
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're just converting hundredths of seconds to an interval here you know.

Comment: suppose if i get 150 value in v_exec_time variable. I want to know that value in time format of like HH:MI:SS:MS

Please help me.

Comment: Yeah I understood the question -- as it's pretty simple I wondered which specific part you had a problem with.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. As i am not aware of DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time result. Hence i posted this question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#sthref9684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time` returns time in 1/100ths of seconds (hsecs).

First we can get the number of complete seconds as follows:

```
v_secs := floor(v_exec_time/100);
```

The remainder in hsecs is then

```
v_exec_time - (v_secs*100);
```

You want milliseconds so:

```
v_remainder_ms := (v_exec_time - (v_secs*100)) * 10;
```

Now for the HH:MI:SS part, we can use Oracle date functions.  First convert the value of v_secs to days:

```
v_days := v_secs/60/60/24;
```

Now use that to get an HH:MI:SS value:

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+v_days,'HH24:MI:SS')
```

(Note: need to use HH24 otherwise will get values like '12:00:00:001'!)

And the full HH24:MI:SS:MS value you want is:

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+v_days,'HH24:MI:SS')||':'||TO_CHAR(v_remainder_ms,'FM000')
```

So putting it all together:

```
Declare
   v_start_time number;
   v_end_time number;
   v_exec_time varchar2(100);
   v_secs integer;
   v_remainder_ms integer;
   v_days number;
begin
   v_start_time:=DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

   dbms_output.put_line('Time calculation');

   v_end_time:=DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

   v_exec_time:= (v_end_time-v_start_time);

   v_secs := floor(v_exec_time/100);

   v_remainder_ms := (v_exec_time - (v_secs*100)) * 10;

   v_days := v_secs/60/60/24;

   dbms_output.put_line ('Result='||TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+v_days,'HH24:MI:SS')
        ||':'||TO_CHAR(v_remainder_ms,'FM000'));

end;
```